# Doctrine preUpdate does not actually change entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Doctrine 2.4.6 in my Symfony 2.6.1 project. The problem is that changes made to entity in preUpdate callback are not saved in database. Code follows:

```
class MyListener {
    public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args) {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();
        $args->setNewValue('name', 'test');
        // echo $args->getNewValue('name'); --> prints 'test'
    }
}

class DefaultController extends Controller {
     /**
     * @Route("/commit", name="commit")
     */
    public function commitAction(Request $request) {
      $content = $request->getContent();
      $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');
      /* @var $serializer \JMS\Serializer\Serializer */
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      /* @var $em \Doctrine\Orm\EntityManagerInterface */
      $persons = $serializer->deserialize($content, 'ArrayCollection<AppBundle\Entity\Person>', 'json');
      /* @var $persons \AppBundle\Entity\Person[] */
      foreach($persons as $person) {
        $em->merge($person);
      }
      $em->flush();
      return new JsonResponse($serializer->serialize($persons, 'json')); 
      // Person name is NOT 'test' here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the fine print carefully:  http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate This is a common source of confusion.  The preUpdate event has many limitations.

Answer (score 0):

The `preUpdate` doesn't allow you to make changes to your entities.  You can only use the computed change-set passed to the event to modify primitive field values.  I bet if you check the database you'll see that the Person entities *did* get updated, you just won't see them in the `$persons` variable until the next time you manually retrieve them.

What you'll have to do after the flush is retrieve the entities from the database to see their updates values:

```
$em->flush();

$personIds = array_map(function($person) { return $person->getId(); }, $persons);

$updatedPersons = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Person')->findById($personIds);

return new JsonResponse($serializer->serialize($updatedPersons, 'json'));
```